# Powerbi | let end user choose parameter in api request

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a custom code made in advanced editor to call a rest api from a webservice.
It works but I want it to make possible for the end user to change the 'date' parameter to the date he wants to see.

I have a seperate webservice that sends the available dates.

What I want is a list in the repport where the user can choose the date that is in the code so it calls that data

Can anybody help me with this?

Dynamic M query parameters in Power BI Desktop
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters

The link above is what I want to do. the problem with this solution is that it only works with direct queries and because my api call is custom it is not direct.

I already succeeded in making a parameter and seeing the list of available dates. The problem is getting this into the repport so users can pick it

[Edit parameter view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF3oo.png)

Comment: Not possible. You will have to load in all the data. Look at Dataflows (or other similar) for keeping a data pull from the API stored, then PBI can load this in via there instead of hitting the API every time. Nice thing about dataflows, is each be refreshed independently.